# Проблема -Jbutton'ы прорисовываются в Jpanel только после наведения мышью

Tags: java, swing

Jpanel содержит 10х10 Jbutton кнопок через GridLayout. Проблема в том, что кнопки прорисовываются только после наведения на них мышью, также после сворачивания-разворачивания окна - аналогичная проблема с прорисовкой (она сбрасывается). 
Читал подобные проблемы на stackoverflow - нигде аналогичной не нашёл, практически везде "неправильно" использовались методы paint... Но в моём случае нет ничего похожего.
 1. [отдельная клетка](https://github.com/AntonKostyukewicz/MineSweeper_game/blob/master/gui/newgame_objects/GraphicCell.java) (сам Jbutton)
 2. [JPanel](https://github.com/AntonKostyukewicz/MineSweeper_game/blob/master/gui/newgame_objects/CellField.java) на котором расположены кнопки
 3. [ну и само окно](https://github.com/AntonKostyukewicz/MineSweeper_game/blob/master/gui/BeginGame.java) на котором располагается Jpanel. Остальные элементы окна (таймеры и т.п.) прорисовываются нормально.

Прошу помочь в решении проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Была аналогичная проблема, полечилось тем, что инструкцию

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

поставил после всех действий с фреймом, те.  после добавления панелек, кнопочек и пр.